# rails cannot perform migrations and modify the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubymine

when I tried to access some of my SQLite db records through RubyMine IDE(5.4.1/4.0.3), I got the following error stack trace:

> com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
>       at com.intellij.persistence.database.console.RemoteJdbcServer.main(RemoteJdbcServer.java:15)

```
in RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:118)
```

Furthermore, I can no longer modify the database structure. When performing the usual migrations through the command line, no particular error message is prompted, but an endless string of random characters forcing me to quit the process.

I am pretty sure it has something to do with a missing file somewhere in my rails project. I am new to rails and honestly have no idea how to fix it. Help would be much appreciated:)

Comment: did u switch from windows to linux or something?

Comment: does it work in the normal command line, not in your RubyMine IDE command line?

Comment: I use Windows 7, never switched back and forth. I am not using RubyMine IDE command line, but the normal one.